# node.js Why data from post requests that is saved in a json file resets to initial empty array after restart server?

Tags: node.js, json, express, http, fs

I am working with express node.js, and I am trying to save datas from post request in a json file. but for some reason when I restart the server, my data from post request was supposed to save in roomDB.json file doesnt remain instead it resets to initial empty array...
Could anyone please advice? thank you very much.

here is my code

```
//saving function

const fs = require("fs");
exports.save =(data, PATH) =>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.writeFile(PATH, JSON.stringify(data), function(err) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve();
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

```
// code in router file to make requests

const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const fs = require("fs");
const rooms = ("./roomDB.json");
const { addRoom} = require("./rooms");


router.get("/", (req, res)=>{
       fs.readFile("roomDB.json", (err, data)=>{
         if(err) return res.status(400);
         res.send(roomDB_PATH)
       })

});

router.get("/:id", (req, res)=>{
    res.send("connect to  a room");
});


router.post("/", (req, res)=>{
    let roomName = req.body;
    if(!roomName.name){
        res.status(404);
        res.end();
        return;
    }
 let room =addRoom(roomName.name);

res.status(201).send(room)

})

module.exports = router;
```

```
 */
const uuid = require("uuid");
let roomdatas;
const {save} = require("./save");
const roomDB_PATH = "roomDB.json";

try {

  roomdatas = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(roomDB_PATH)); 
} catch (e) {

    roomdatas = []
    save(roomdatas, roomDB_PATH);
}

const addRoom = (roomName) => {
    roomName = roomName.trim().toLowerCase();
    const existingRoom = roomdatas.find((room) => room.name === roomName);

    if (existingRoom) {
        return { error: 'chatroom has existed' };
    }
    let room = {
        name: roomName,
        id: uuid.v4(),
        messages: [],
        users: [],
        created: +new Date()
    };
    roomdatas.push(room);
    save(roomdatas, roomDB_PATH);
    return { room };
};

module.exports ={addRoom};
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are encountering an error with the `JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(roomDB_PATH));` call. This code runs every time your server is started (when you import the file into your router file), and if it encounters an error it is resetting the file to an empty array. Try logging the error to see what is causing it. You're currently completely suppressing the error with no way to tell why it is failing.